# sharing a link on facebook displays the wrong image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharing

i'm facing a problem with sharing links on facebook which is displaying the wrong image many times and just sometimes it displays the correct image using the code like this

```
<meta property="og:title" content="webpage title" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain.com/webpage_url.php?id=17515278817738945084phb">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="app id here"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.domain.com/large/image.jpg" />
```

and when debugging the page i get this

```
The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
```

this image is 1000*317px and still not showing up. this happens with all the links of my site. I have to go to url debugger and clear the cache so facebook can get the correct image. so how to fix this problem and make facebook display the correct image directly?
[UPDATE]
using the facebook debugger i get this notice

```
og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a 
chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and 
is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://www.domain.com/gallery1/01234.jpg' will 
be used instead.
```

But the og:image is set properly and image size is largr than 200*200 and Facebook displays the correct image after clearing the Facebook cache though it keeps displaying this notice

Comment: If you had not implemented Open Graph meta tags correctly before, and Facebook has already scraped those URLs, then you need to get them re-scraped, so that Facebook can pick up the correct data now. You can also [trigger a re-scrape via API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update), if you need to do it for a lot of links automatically.

Comment: No they are new URLs with the above Open Graph meta tags and Facebook didn't cache those URLs yet

Comment: Well then you should fix any errors the debug tool shows first. As long as you’re getting `The 'og:type' property is required, but not present`, something seems to be wrong.

Comment: "og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough." but the image is there and larger than 200*200 and Facebookr ecognized it after clearing Facebook cache using the debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pointing to your index file. eg www.yourdomain.com/index.php when using the facebook object debugger. It fixed the og:name error for me.